# Mail Server has stopped working on Ubuntu server 14 since instlling MailScanner

Tags: ubuntu, postfix

I installed Mail Server on Ubuntu Server 14: (tutorial https://www.linuxcbt.com/products_linuxcbt_postfix_edition)

**1.** Postfix + dovecot - works properly without MailScanner

**2.** ClamAV - clamd

**3.** Spamassassin

**4.** MailScanner

After install MailScanner mail server did not work.

A few years ago I did the same thing on OpenSuse11 and server running to this day. On Ubuntu I do not know why do not want to work.

difference between Ubuntu and OpenSuse

On Ubuntu Server 
Postfix configuration file `/etc/postfix/main.cf` there was no

```
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
```

there was no file `header_checks`

```
/etc/postfix/header_checks
```

when I remove the line `header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks` from file `main.cf`  server work.

Maybe this is simple solution, but..... I have no idea?

Thank you in advance for your help

**main.cf**

```
cat main.cf

# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/server.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = mantykora.cleoni.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = mantykora.cleoni.com, localhost.cleoni.com, , localhost, cleoni.com
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 192.168.1.0/24
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4

# Wlodek 2016 02 11

home_mailbox = Maildir/
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = cleoni.com
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes

smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_non_fqdn_hostname, reject_invalid_hostname  

#Wlodek 2016 02 12 to support MailScanner

header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
```

**MailScanner.conf** I add this https://www.mailscanner.info/postfix/#

```
%org-name% = Cleoni
%org-long-name% = Cleoni Unix
%web-site% = cleoni.pl

Run As User = postfix
Run As Group = postfix
MTA = postfix

Incoming Queue Dir = /var/spool/postfix/hold
Outgoing Queue Dir = /var/spool/postfix/incoming

Virus Scanners = clamav


Spam List = SBL+XBL


SpamAssassin User State Dir = /var/spool/MailScanner/spamassassin
```

[image]

Comment: Pls post your `main.cf` and `MailScanner.conf`, also I assume that your `/etc/postfix/header_checks` looks so `/^Received:/ HOLD` if you have something else there, then post it as well

Comment: yes - /etc/postfix/header_checkss - /^Received:/ HOLD

Comment: `Outgoing Queue Dir = /var/spool/postfix/incoming` looks very suspicious. btw you cannot send receive or both?

Comment: i add screen OpenSuse on OpenSuse this work

Comment: Can you run MailScanner --lint on your server and post the results here too. On a side note if you are using clamd set Virus Scanners = clamd  in MailScanner.conf.